# how to apply LUT filter with movie filter in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

movie=logo [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[out];

By giving image input using movie filter, I want to make watermark image transparent.I written code in visual c++. Please help to correct command syntax to pass filter description into filter graph.

Comment: `movie=logo,lut=... [watermark];`

Comment: with this command getting error : Output pad "default" with type video of the filter instance "in" of buffer not connected to any destination

Comment: @Nayan Show your full command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard movie=logo [watermark];[watermark] lute=a=val*0.3[a];[a]overlay=0:0

Comment: @LordNeckbeard This is the full command i am trying in ffmpeg.exe. "ffmpeg –i inputvideo.mp4 -vf "movie=logo [watermark];[watermark]lut=a=val*0.3[a];[a]overlay=0:0 outputvideo.mp4" but actually, I am implementing this in my project using FFMPEG source code's avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filter_descr,&inputs, &outputs, NULL).I have created two filters "in" and "out". and passing above command in filter_description argument.

Comment: You should show your actual code.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard That issue i have solved but another issue coming is video's timescode is liittle bit jumping with movie filter.you can generate using this command in ffmpeg.exe.ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i mylogo.png -filter_complex "[1]lut=a=val*0.3[a];[0][a]overlay=0:0, drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=14.832000: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" -c:v libx264 -an output.mp4

Comment: @Nayan If you found a solution to the original problem you should post an answer here. Then make a new question for your new problem.

Comment: for the above problem i have implemented -complex filter in my code so that filter chain work properly with more than one inputs/outputs and initialize all the filters properly.